# How the shortcut keys related to Canvas app behaves in Salesforce? Would it still work?

Tags: canvas

The canvas app which i am trying to use it in the visualforce page having bunch of shortcut keys to do certain activities.

But if i use the shortcut keys, sometimes it does not recognize and the key strokes and combination of key strokes fires up the browser event.

So far i did not try the canvas app inside a console and i do not know exactly how the shortcut keys for canvas app collide with shortcut keys of console.

My questions are,

1. How the shortcut keys related to a Canvas app behaves in Salesforce? Would it work?
2. What should i do if i need to use the shortcut keys for my canvas app?

Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 1):

> How the shortcut keys related to a Canvas app behaves in Salesforce? Would it work?

Access keys work on all browsers that support them, so of course your canvas app can use access keys. Furthermore, access keys won't conflict with any access keys in salesforce.com, because they are in separate windows (and thus, separate contexts, etc).

> What should i do if i need to use the shortcut keys for my canvas app?

You must first have *focus* on your canvas app. This means that the user has to click within the canvas area, or you must cause focus by using autofocus on an input element or calling a script on page load to gain focus. Other than that, they work exactly as it would in a normal browsing context.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. My canvas app is a SAP netweaver Web GUI. It have its own shortcut keys like Shift+F7 to open a sales order screen, Alt+F8 to enable edit mode of the sales order screen. All these access keys are already built-in the app. As per your suggestion, I would give a try to see if the focus inside the canvas app let me use the shortcut keys meant for it. Thanks.